# Connection to URL

Tags: java, android, web-services, url

This is my code

```
try{
URL url = new URL("url to tes");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.connect();

if(urlConnection.getResponseCode()==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
   test=true
}catch()...

if(test){
    tv.setText("yesssss");
}else{
    tv.setText("noooo");
```

info: so I put this code on my mainActivity to test if I know how to connect on a url. My goal is to connect to web service that return me a json. But first I want to know how to connect.

> Do you know a url that I can test with this code?
>    And my code here, is he good for connection?

Also `tv` is my TextView it work. It was to minimise the code.

I know after that I got to catch the `InputStream` and work with it to catch my json.

Comment: Use this url https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1 it returns JSON response.

Comment: read some tutorials :https://www.javatpoint.com/android-web-service

Comment: thx for your url, now the real problem begin, my test above return me `noooo`. What is wrong my test, or it really fail.

Answer (score 0):

Use URLUtil to validate the URL as below.

```
URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)
```

It will return True if URL is valid and false if URL is invalid.